# Parallel MOSFETs in saturation/active region

Tags: mosfet, parallel

Am I right that when MOSFETs are connected in parallel for them to share the current equally (See [Parallel MOSFETs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/parallel-mosfets)) they have to be operated in the *triode* region?

I have an electronic load with 3 parallel MOSFETs and one opamp with 1 shunt in the negative feedback configuration with the opamp driving all 3 MOSFET gates and when in the active region all the current goes through one of the MOSFETs.

What is the easiest way to get a more even current distribution in the active region in this application?

[image: basic electronic load]

Comment: Likely, use a 20mΩ sense for each one, and drive each gate individually.

Comment: What is the minimum voltage drop and maximum current required?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, Minimum voltage drop as low as possible, max current - 10A. I was testing at the voltage drop of 36V and the current 1.5A when it was very noticable that all the current was going through one MOSFET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Am I right that when MOSFETs are connected in parallel for them to
> share the current equally (See Parallel MOSFETs) they have to be
> operated in the triode region?*

Yes, that is quite correct but, you could get lucky and have a reasonably even spread. When operated in their linear region not only is the current sharing ambiguous but one device can really hog all the current due to the gate-source control voltage being below the zero-temperature-coefficient point. The knock-on effect of this is that all three devices can blow up within milli-seconds.

Reason: one hogs all the current demanded as by the control circuit and it gets warmer and takes more drain current before the control system can respond and you are in a vicious circle where the device fails rapidly in a hot-spot area inside the silicon. It's called the [spirito effect](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/mosfet-safe-operating-area-and-hot-swap-circuits.html).

Once this happens (and it can happen as quickly as a few tens of microseconds) the remaining MOSFETs (previously not called into action) are "forming a queue" for it to happen to them.

> *What is the easiest way to get a more even current distribution in the
> active region in this application?*

Well if there is a silver bullet it's three op-amps and three current sense resistors; not elegant but practical; three parallel and independent current sources/sinks.

More on the Spirito Effect in questions and answers on this site: -

- [Burning a MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397467/burning-a-power-mosfet/397511#397511)
- [Heat dissipation in MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472375/heat-dissipation-calculation-for-mosfet/472587#472587)
- [More stuff](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349011/how-many-mosfets-can-a-linear-controller-handle/349017#349017)

Comment: With perfect MOSFET your answer would be untrue, but there are no perfect components, they have variations. I have also heard that this phenomena is called "Wolf pack", the weakest sheep is caught first and then the second and so on...

Comment: If there was a god for MOSFETs my answer would also be untrue but there isn't. I'm also thinking that you haven't realized that this can happen to a single MOSFET if operated below the ZTC point @MatsKarlsson. Thermal runaway in a single MOSFET is a fact despite the believed myths about MOSFETs.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I should have stayed away from low Rds_on MOSFETs for this application to avoid the Spirito Effect. Hope it works for the short duration application I need it for. Hasn't exploded so far :)

Comment: I wonder if this ZTC parameter only applies to the linear/triode region or to the active/saturation region as well. I see linear in your answer, does it mean the TC is always good (not sure positive or negative) in the saturation/active region?

Comment: It affects the MOSFET saturation region. Most data sheets show graphs if you compare yours with graphs in the other links I provided.

Comment: Hm, looking at IXTA15N50L2 (linear mosfet) datasheet and the temperature coefficient for I_d(V_gs) is always positive (Fig. 7), would expect it to be negative with a low ZTC. https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_n-channel_linear_ixt_15n50_datasheet.pdf.pdf

Comment: IXYS have a good range and this device looks like it might converge off the graph to the right. However, if you look how much ID changes with temperature it isn't a great deal ratio wise compared to MOSFETs suitable for switching applications. In other words, where ID is greater, the relative change of ID with temperature is not massive.