# Design or selection of a capacitive-load soft start circuit

Tags: power-electronics, soft-starter

A circuit to soft-start, a.k.a. slew-limit, the charging of a 220 uF capacitor Cf at a maximum current in the neighbourhood of 300 mA. Cf is a filter cap preceding a further SMPS stage. My plan so far is to use an ESL227M035AG8AA, an aluminum electrolytic chosen for its ESR of 48 mohm @ 100 kHz. 220 uF was slightly arbitrary, only chosen because the SMPS asks for a minimum of 20 uF at the input with low ESR, and the 220 uF cap is the cheapest in that category.

Tony says that

> If ESR * C <= 10 us ( for low ESR type e-caps) then Ic max = Vin/ESR = Vin * C /10us = 18V * 22 = ~ 400 Amps

In this case this would be basically true, because 48 mohm * 220 uF = 10.56 us; and 18 V * 220 uF / 10.56 us = 375 A.

Vin between 12 and 18 V. This is automotive line voltage but can go that high due to some non-standard modifications from hobbyists for this application.

Maximum continuous load is 1.1 A. The load is a simple SMPS powering a LED driver. The SMPS has its own soft-start circuit but of course can only protect its output, not capacitors at its input.

U1 would be replaced based on design parameters but a quick hack uses the default PMOS model for simulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSOjy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Simulation time-domain]

Based on a [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/577079/soft-start-circuit-problem), at these time scales U1 risks entering thermal runaway and there is barely any other resistance in the charging path so it could fry due to the Spirito effect. However, am I right in thinking that if I use something like the [MCG35P04](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/MCG35P04(DFN3333).pdf) which has only a weak thermal effect against Vgs:

[image: Vgs against Id]

then runaway may be mitigated?

It's possible to replace the PMOS with an NMOS and put it only in the charging path of the capacitor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCsVIr.png)</sup>

Speaking more broadly, it surprises me that manufacturers don't seem to offer integrated soft-start circuits for this purpose - only soft-start sections in *other* components like SMPS or load switches. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the end application is, but you shouldn't need to really worry about having a soft start circuit for this small of a capacitive load.

Comment: @bunker89320  heh !  If ESR * C <= 10 us ( for low ESR type e-caps) then Ic max = Vin/ESR = Vin * C /10us = 18V * 22 = ~ 400 Amps. But the correct approach is to use a PFM buck regulator with soft start

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's very interesting to me and I would like to hear why; because it seems to set up a chicken-or-egg. SMPS ask for an input capacitor, but input capacitors ask for inrush protection.

Comment: That's why some DCDC conv. IC's have realtime current limiting to precharge output enable from DC OK signal.

Comment: Why do you need such a big cap? what is the source & load?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Don't need such a big cap; the AP64200 SMPS specsheet calls for Cin > 20uF but this 220uF is the cheapest low-ESR one in this category. I could decrease it and pay a little more. Source is automotive line voltage (but from customizers who can often run higher than 12V). Load is a LED driver.

Comment: Why not just use 2x 10µF X7R ceramic caps? That will give you much lower ESR, cost less, and solve your problem...

Comment: @bobflux Lower ESR makes the inrush situation worse, right? Are you suggesting that the inrush be mitigated by spreading it out over multiple components? 375A / 2 doesn't seem good enough.