# MOSFET working in saturation region @ low Vgs

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to regulate a "low current" (20A) by the controlling the voltage between the source and the gate of a MOSFET SiC. I want to make the MOSFET work into this region :

[image]

Nevertheless it is not able to regulate 20A. The setup is the following :

[image]

I set the power supply in voltage mode and limit it current to 21A. At the beginning I set the voltage VGS to 15V. And I slowly decrease the voltage VGS to hope that at a certain voltage it will limit the current to 20A. At a certain VGs around 3V, the current starts to oscillate. I was not expecting this. I was thinking it will stop conduct if the vgs was too low but I wasn't thinking that it will oscilatte. Then toward 2V, it stops conducting.

Is it normal to see the current oscillating when Vgs is near the threshold voltage ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Is your observation of the LTspice simulation only, or a test-bench physical power supply?

Comment: test bench physical power supply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it normal to see the current oscillating when Vgs is near the
> threshold voltage ?*

It's oscillating because the power supply is current limited and, it's the current limiting circuit that is defining the frequency of oscillation. Be very careful that you don't damage the MOSFET in this region; the MOSFET will have a temperature coefficient that will cause really rapid thermal runaway as documented in google and on some of my answers: -

- [Spirito effect #1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545800/is-this-gate-driver-circuit-sufficient-to-drive-a-parallel-fet-spot-welder/545806#545806)
- [Spirito effect #2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522003/parallel-mosfets-in-saturation-active-region/522025#522025)
- [Spirito effect #3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349011/how-many-mosfets-can-a-linear-controller-handle/349017#349017)
- [The lie they told me about MOSFETs when I was at college](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472375/heat-dissipation-calculation-for-mosfet/472587#472587)
- [Burning a power MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397467/burning-a-power-mosfet/397511#397511)

Comment: But why it enter into oscillation ? At Vgs = 15V, the power supply is limiting the current and it does not oscillate ? I agree on the thermal runaway

Comment: The current limit circuit in the power supply works on a knife-edge; at 20 volts and 20.99 amps it isn't current limiting whereas at 21.00 amps, the current limit circuit will potentially drop the output voltage to 0 volts. If you had a 1 ohm power resistor in series with the drain (also in series with the supply) it might help stop the oscillation because it blunts the "knife edge" a little. At a Vgs of 15 volts the MOSFET is thoroughly in the ohmic region and, no matter what you do with the power supply, it'll remain in the ohmic region and not cause the power supply to oscillate.

Comment: However, if you dropped the power supply voltage to around 0.2 volts, it might start oscillating a little bit with Vgs = 15 volts.

Comment: But if the MOSFET begin to limit the current rather than the power supply it should stabilize.

Comment: You can't really say that because the power supply's current limit circuit is not expecting to deal with a load (your MOSFET) that also has a fairly knife-edge characteristic AND, any delay circuits in the power supply's limiting circuit will turn it into an oscillator.

Comment: Ok ok ... so I have to change my setup

Comment: Just try adding a lowish value series resistor to connect power supply to MOSFET. Maybe  even 0.1 ohm might work @Jess. It should prove what I'm saying.

Comment: And you think that I can suceed to regulate 20A at a voltage so near to the threshold voltage ? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Jess it's worth trying just to prove the mechanism.